# Сформировать новый массив, содержащий повторяющиеся элементы массива A

Tags: массивы, pascal

Пример:
Вход:
-1 -1 2 3 9 6 7 6 0 0
Выход:
-1 6 0
Элементы в новом массиве не повторяются
Просьба хотя бы пояснить или намекнуть на решение.
Заранее спасибо

```
for i:=1 to n do
    begin
        j:=1;
        while (j<=n) and (a[i]<>a[j]) and (i<>j) do
            j:=j+1;
        if j<=n then
        begin
            k:=1;
            b[k]:=a[i];
            inc(k);
        end;    
    end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня получилось это:

[image]

Код программы:

```
    Var
      Mas, Mass: Array[0..99] Of Integer;
      i, j, k, u, n, m: Byte;
      Flag: Boolean;

    begin
      Repeat
        Write('Vvedi razmer massiva (1 < N < 100), N = ');
        ReadLn(N);
      Until ((N > 1) And (N < 100));

      WriteLn('Vvedi massiv:');
      N:=N-1;
      For i:=0 To N Do
        Begin
          Write('Mas[', i+1, '] = ');
          ReadLn(Mas[i]);
        End;

// самое интересное начинается здесь
      M:=N-1; // без этой переменной можно обойтись
      k:=0; // кол-во элементов формируемого массива
      For i:=0 To M Do // мотаю цикл от 0 до предпоследнего элемента
        For j:=i+1 To N Do // мотаю цикл от текущего до последнего элемента
          If (Mas[i] = Mas[j]) Then // если просматриваемые элементы равны
            Begin
                Flag:=False; // флаг
                For u:=0 To k-1 Do // мотаю цикл от 0 до кол-ва эл-тов нового массива
                // если такой эл-т в новом массиве уже есть
                  If (Mas[i] = Mass[u]) Then
                    Begin
                      Flag:=True; // флаг - истина
                      Break; // выход из цикла
                    End;
                 // если такой эл-т в новом массиве уже есть
                If (Flag) Then Continue; // переход к следующей итерации цикла

                Mass[k]:=Mas[i]; // элемент в новый массив
                k:=k+1; // кол-во эл-тов нового массива +1
            End;

       WriteLn;
       WriteLn('------Tvoi massiv:------');
       WriteLn;

       k:=k-1;
       For i:=0 To k Do // ну, а здесь просто и тупо вывод массива
         WriteLn(Mass[i]);

      WriteLn;
      WriteLn('Davi na ENTER!');
      ReadLn;
    end.
```

Answer (score 0):

Берем цикл
переберем все элементы исходного массива, каждый элемент проверяем на условие если соответствует, то копируем в новый массив.

Comment: написал код, но он выводит только первые два элемента исходного массива

Comment: Владимир Владимирович, `k:=1;` надо делать до цикла, а то вы каждый раз в один и тот же элемент записываете. Кстати, а кокой размер массива `b`?

Answer (score 0):

Отсортировать массив, а дальше проход по отсортированному массиву и счетчик на количество повторений, если содержимое счетчика больше 1, число повторяется.